# Am Getting Answer In Reverse, When Time Is 0 -11 Hrs It's Printing Good Evening

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import datetime
import random
t = datetime.datetime.now()
print(t)
if(t.hour == random.randint(0,11)):
    print("Good Morning")   
else:
    print("Good Evening")
```

Comment: This code generates a number between 0 and 11, and prints "Good Morning" as long as the current hour is equal to the random number it just generated. As long as you run this code in the morning, I'd expect it to print "Good Morning" 1 out of 12 runs, on average. Should this be `if t.hour < 12`?

Comment: @RobGwynn-Jones
But Its Printing In Reverse 
I Tried With t.hour < 12 Also 
Getting Same Output.. 
Now Its 12:15 PM Here It Printing "Good Morning"

Comment: If you add e.g. `print("{}".format(t.hour))` what does it show?

Answer (score 3):

You're matching the current hour with a randomly picked hour between 0 and 11, so chances are you will not find a match. If you want to test if the current hour is between 0 and 11, you should simply use chained comparison operations:

```
if 0 <= t.hour <= 11:
    print("Good Morning")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the following line of code in your program:

```
if(t.hour == random.randint(0,11)):
```

Here, you are comparing t.hour (the current hour) with a randomly generated integer between 0 and 11.

If `t.hour` lies between `0-11`, the probability of this statement evaluating to true is equal to the probability of `random.randint(0,11)` generating the same integer, which is `1/12`. Hence, chances of printing "Good Evening" are `11/12`.

The correct way to do this would be:

```
if 0 <= t.hour <= 11:
    print("Good Morning")   
else:
    print("Good Evening")
```